Объясните, как научить бота в Minecraft крафтить предметы в инвентаре на Python? (Javascript, Mineflayer)
@On(bot, 'chat')
def inventory2(this, user, message, *args):
    if 'доски' in message:
        oak_log_count = 0
        for item in bot.inventory:
            if item == 'oak_log':
                oak_log_count += bot.inventory[item]
        
        if oak_log_count >= 1:
            bot.craft('oak_planks', count=4)  # Скрафтить 4 доски из бревен дуба
            bot.chat('Скрафчены доски!')
            bot.equip(bot.registry.itemsByName['oak_planks'].id, 'hand')


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
